# Why does --x; work and x-- gives seg fault in recursion code

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault

This code gives me a seg fault, but when I change the `x--` to `--x` it prints correctly.

Are not they the same????

```
int main()
{    
    myFunc(5); 
    return 0;
}

void myFunc (int x) {  
    if (x > 0) {
        myFunc(x--);
        printf("%d, ", x);
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

Comment: Aha a case of stack overflow!!

Comment: @another.anon.coward Surprisingly no in this case. MSVC is able to treat this is a tail-recursion... EDIT: I take that back. You have to move the `printf()` to the start of the function call (as in my answer) to get it to be a tail-recursion.

Comment: @Mysticial: Oh ... but generally isn't infinite recursion one of the common causes for stack overflow? As you have said, maybe the compiler *optimizes* this case into a tail recursion

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No they are not the same.

The difference between `x--` and `--x` is whether the returned value is before or after the decrement.

In `myFunc(x--)`, `x--` returns the old value. So `myFunc()` gets called repeatability with the same value -> infinite recursion.

In `myFunc(--x)`, `--x` returns the new value. So `myFunc()` gets called with a decreasing number each time -> no infinite recursion.

---

It will be easier to see this if you moved your `printf` to the start of the function call:

```
void myFunc (int x) {  
    printf("%d, ", x);

    if (x > 0) {
        myFunc(x--);

    }
    else
        return;
}
```

**Output:** (when called with 10)

```
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, ...
```

Answer (score 5):

The post-decrement operation (`x--`) takes place *after* the argument is evaluated, so `myFunc` is repeatedly called with the *same* value. The pre-decrement (`--x`) operation takes place *before* the argument is evaluated, which works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Because the modification of -- is either post or pre.  When you call x-- it is post, and therefore runs after myFunc is called, in this case doing nothing.  --x will be called before myFunc and therefore will affect x.

Answer (score 1):

x-- decrements the variable after the use. This is the reason why you pass to your function always the same value, that should be decreased, but doesn't, as well as the function repeats itself.